# Why can't my neural network learn to recover information from input?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, theano, conv-neural-network

I am trying to set up a neural network to learn to predict the consensus statistic given several input statistics (for multiple data points in each sample).

In other words my input data is of the shape (n_samples, n_statistics, n_points)
and output is (n_samples, 1_consensus_statistic, n_points).

The Neural Network us supposed to learn the single consensus output given n_statistics about it; possibly data in the other n_points might help recovering the relationship so it might be worth adding a fully connected layer. Note that one of the n_statistics resembles the 1_consensus_stat well in terms of magnitude (most of n_points are about 3.1, but some values are small (0.5 or  0.2) and the first and third of the n_statistics resemble that well; the other of the n_statistics are smaller values but also there should be a nonlinear relationship between them and the consensus output - i.e. they should help the network learn the consensus statistic).

Instead the network learns to predict that all n_points are about 2.5-3.0 in magnitude. Somehow it manages to loose the information would could be retrieved from a simple linear regression model. Here is my setup in Keras. What am I doing wrong?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LocallyConnected1D(n_points, 3, input_shape=(n_statistics=6,n_points),  kernel_initializer="uniform"), activation='relu')
model.add(AveragePooling1D(strides=2))
model.add(LocallyConnected1D(n_points, 2, kernel_initializer="uniform"), activation='relu')
model.add(Dense(n_points, activation='relu',  kernel_initializer="uniform"))
model.add(Dense(n_points, activation='softplus', kernel_initializer="uniform")) 

model.compile(optimizer='adamax', loss='mean_squared_logarithmic_error', metrics=['mse'])
```

Comment: how do you preprocess the data? this may be important so that people can see your entire process

Comment: I don't preprocess at all. I have as the input the array of shape input_shape=(n_statistics=6,n_points). And it is just pure numbers between 0.2 and 4.0. actually statistic 1 reflects magnitude of output pretty well, statistic 2 not so well (numbers are small, maximum is about 1.0) etc.

Comment: Normalize your input data

Comment: and leave the output unnormalized? Otherwise I loose some of the information...

Comment: Why would you lose information? You don't have to normalize output..

Comment: I normalized the inputs and I get what happens quite often when I try training networks. The output converges to to some level of accuracy, all output points have the same value, for  example 0,6. sometime all get 0.0 etc. It really seems like something is fundamentally wrong with the network setup.